# Python 3.7.3: I'm getting a SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm getting a SyntaxError but the error points to nothing that makes sense

I've already tried moving around the code a bit & searched google for the error but nothing's helped

````
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 arg=reason
 author=ctx.author
 guild=ctx.message.guild
 perms=discord.Permissions(connect=False, speak=False, read_text_channels_&_see_voice_channels=False, add_reactions=False, send_messages=False)
 role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")

 await guild.create_role(name="muted", colour=discord.Colour(0x808080), permissions=perms)
 await member.send(f'You got muted for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Muted by: {author}')
 await member.add_roles(role)
 await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} got muted for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Muted by: {author}!')
````

The error message is: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression and then it highlights in red where I put the ^

````
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 arg=reason
 author=ctx.author
 guild=ctx.message.guild
 perms=discord.Permissions(connect=False, speak=False, read_text_channels_&_see_voice_channels=False, add_reactions=False
```                                                   ^
````

Comment: You need to do the assignment `perms=discord.Permissions(connect=False, speak=False, read_text_channels_&_see_voice_channels=False, add_reactions=False, send_messages=False)` outside the function definition, and pass the assigned variable to function like `perms=perms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple: you have an `&` in `read_text_channels_&_see_voice_channels`, which I believe you intend to be the name of an argument.

As `&` cannot be in names, Python parses that as `read_text_channels_ & _see_voice_channels`, which is the same as applying the `&` operator (binary and) to `read_text_channels_` and `_see_voice_channels`.

Comment: ```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connect'``` @gmds now I got that error

Comment: @DrJakaboii You should ask a different question then. Anyway [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions) shows that the constructor takes only a `permissions` argument. Maybe you want to use the `update` method to set the other values.

Comment: I can never understand the documentation, I'll ask another question